# Checkbox in specific label

Tags: c#, forms, checkbox, label

It's really easy but complicated to explain:

I have checkboxes, 10 in total but there is a limit, we can only check 5 of the 10.
Let's imagine that we tick a box in two and press validate. 
I would get a bool array that looks like this:

true, false, true, false, false, true, false, false, false, false

Knowing that each box has a value:
first box = Animal
second box = Capital....

Now I come to my question:

I have 5 labels and I would like it to be 5 labels corresponding to the value of the checkbox.
So how to make it 5 labels is all a different value that corresponds to the checkbox.

Here is my code:

```
    bool[] categorie = new bool[10] { 
        false, true, false ,true ,false ,
        true ,false ,true, false, true };

    string[] categorieName = new string[10] {
       "Animaux", "Capitale", "Fruit", "Légume", "Pays", 
       "Prénom fille", "Prénom garçon", "Métier", "Moyen de transport", "Sport" };
```

So I have already completed the bool array but it completes itself by itself according to the checkboxes

And the second is value.

so I would like my labels to be:

Capitale, Légume, pays, prénom garcon, moyen de transport

Thank you for having and please explain a solution (loop for ? if? I don't know)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's organize the `CheckBox`es into a collection, say, array:

```
 Tuple<CheckBox, Control>[] m_Categories = null;

 public MyForm() {
   // I've assumed WinForms - InitializeComponent()
   InitializeComponent();

   // CheckBox and its corresponding Label
   m_Categories = new Tuple<CheckBox, Control>[] {
     Tuple.Create(cbAnimaux, labelAnimaux),   
     Tuple.Create(cbCapitale, labelCapitale),     
     ...
     Tuple.Create(cbSport, labelSport), 
   };
 }
```

Then you can easily update corresponding `Label`s:

```
 foreach (var record in m_Categories)
   record.Item2.Text = record.Item1.Checked // If CheckBox is  
     ? record.Item1.Text // checked, label gets CheckBoxes Text
     : "";               // not checked, label has an empty Text
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but there is another problem:
the checkboxes are in a separate form and I get them back thanks to the class parameter (that's why I have an array)